# SNS client timeout

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I'm trying to set the timeout to SNS client `send` request.

```
const snsClient = new SNSClient({
      region: region,
      requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
        httpsAgent: new Agent({
          keepAlive: true
        }),
        connectionTimeout: 25000
      }) as any
    });

const input: PublishCommandInput = {...};
const sendMessage = new PublishCommand(input);

const result = await req.sns.send(sendMessage);
```

I'm reusing the client between lambda invocation and want to keep the connection alive. Here I'm trying to abort the `send` after X seconds. Is there any way to set the timeout to request?